# How to play video on hover/pause when not hovering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I Using the code below, I have been able to successfully make a function that plays a video on hover.

```
     <div id="vid">
     <video onmouseover="this.play()" 
        onmouseout="this.pause();this.currentTime=;">
            <source src="PISTOL.mp4"></source>
           </video>    
            </div>

                <script>
            var figure = $(".video");
            var vid = figure.find("video");

            [].forEach.call(figure, function (item,index) {
                item.addEventListener('mouseover', hoverVideo.bind(item,index), false);
                item.addEventListener('mouseout', hideVideo.bind(item,index), false);
            });

            function hoverVideo(index, e) {
                vid[index].play(); 
            }

            function hideVideo(index, e) {
                vid[index].pause(); 
            }
            </script>
```

however, i want to make it so that instead of the video stopping when you hover-off, it just pauses. And when you hover on again, the video plays where you left off. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Where does it break?

Comment: i'm sorry i don't understand the question...

Comment: How far do you get. Why does it — not — pause on `mouseout`?

Comment: i'm not sure why.. the video plays as long as my mouse pointer is on the video. When i hover-off, it goes back to the start of the video...

Comment: @AjAX. i added something new to my code in the post, maybe the discrepancy is there??

Comment: `this.currentTime=` is probably the cause of the "rewind".

Comment: Yeah. What is this `currentTime` stub? What does it do without?

Comment: hmm... let me check what the output is without it

Comment: Also you have two `eventListeners` attached. One `inline` and one in `code`. That stacks up. Perhaps try with only one.

Comment: @AjAX. THANK YOU! the discrepancy was there, i just had to remove the currentTime. turns out, it set the time for when the video will resume playing

Comment: Cool (Y). All good.

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen Ok. Right. Stopped in code review just about that empty `array`. %)P It was before the adding of the `HTML`. And it had to come somewhere from. The at-least-half-working-thing.

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen didn't see your reply a while ago... but thanks nonetheless for answering!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There’s a typo and unnecessary code:

```
onmouseout="this.pause();this.currentTime=;">
```

Should be:

```
onmouseout="this.pause();">
```

That should do it.